# railsadmin to show records for current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In RailsAdmin, how can I config it so that it only shows record associated to the current user? Right now, every 'admin' login will see everyone's records.

I want admin1 login to see only what's associated to admin1. Admin1 should not see Admin2's data.

I am not using Devise, Sorcery or Cancancan. All done manually at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

In rails_admin.rb, add:

```
config.current_user_method do
    user = User.find_by( id:session[ :user_id ] )
end
config.authorize_with :cancan
```

In ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user && user.admin?
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :dashboard
      can :manage, User,    id: user.id
      can :manage, Manager, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Staff,   manager: { user_id: user.id }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something like this:

https://github.com/influitive/apartment

If you want to do it manually... you'll want your controller to call a query that will filter to just the results that that user is supposed to have access to... So instead of something like Client.all , you'd use something like current_user.clients ....